# Integrate 3rd Party Flash Component into an Adobe Air Application?

Tags: javascript, html, apache-flex, flash, air

I'm fairly proficient with HTML/Javascript/CSS. It's my understanding that I can write an Adobe Air application using just those technologies. Let's assume I want to convert one of my webapps to an Adobe Air application, but this web app uses a 3rd party Flash component. Can I embed this 3rd party flash component into my Adobe Air application? If so, could you provide any resources on doing such a thing.

Thanks!

Comment: Good question. I'd like to see if there's a positive answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy... You can read about how to create your app html page [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ecc.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7fac)

And if you wanted to embedd a swf file into that html you could use the following code:

```
<object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%"> 
    <param name="movie" value="app:/SWFFile.swf"></param> 
</object>
```

Notice that the path to your swf file is 'app:/SWFFile.swf' that will point your air app to the app install directory.

Comment: This looks like a good answer. I don't see app:/ as being necessary though. You should be able to use a normal path and it will resolve to that when you compile.